# Zend Db SQLITE Setup

Tags: php, zend-framework, sqlite

im trying to setup sqlite as a secondary adapter and have run into a problem.

I am getting the following message:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'reports.reports' doesn't exist
```

My code for the table is:

```
class Table_Reports extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
protected $_name = 'reports';
protected $_id = 'report_id';
protected $_rowClass = 'Model_Report';
protected $_adapter = 'dbReports';
protected $_schema = 'reports';
```

}

If i change the $_schema to blank then it tries to use my primary mysql database.

My app config is:

```
resources.multidb.db1.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.db1.host = "localhost"
resources.multidb.db1.dbname = "test"
resources.multidb.db1.username = "root"
resources.multidb.db1.password = ""
resources.multidb.db1.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

resources.multidb.db2.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE"
resources.multidb.db2.dbname = ROOT "/data/reports.db"
```

Anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

I have turned on Profiling however as far as i can tell nothing is being queried as the error occurs when i run:

```
$reports = new Table_Reports();
$reportRow = $reports->createRow();
```

Comment: Please try [turning on query profiling](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html), which will enable you to get the actual executed SQL.  From that, we can determine exactly what's going wrong.  I'm going to speculate that an `ALTER TABLE` is being run when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort this problem out.

The adapter was using the mysql user and password details to try and connect to sqlite so i have had to force the adapter to change over like so:

```
public function __construct($config = array())
{
    $this->_setAdapter(Zend_Registry::get('dbReports'));
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

This is in the file `class Table_Reports`

Answer (score 2):

Try using APPLICATION_PATH and relative path instead ROOT. Maybe you have open_basedir restriction or authorization problem